# Email activation link query on registration error

Tags: php

I am trying to make this activation link php page that can't seem to get working. Shows error every time I execute.

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /home/abc/public_html/abc.com/confirmation-link-validation.php on line 28

and

> Notice: Undefined variable: result2 in /home/abc/public_html/abc.com/confirmation-link-validation.php on line 55

Code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

include('connection.php');

// Passkey
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con) { die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());}
$db_select=mysqli_select_db($con, "");
if (!$db_select) { die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());}

$tbl_name1="temp_users";

// Retrieve data from "temp_users"
$sql1="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'";
$result1=mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

// If successfully queried
if($result1){

// Count how many row has this passkey
$count=mysqli_num_rows($con, $result1);   Line 28..

// if passkey found, retrieve data from table "temp_members_db"
if($count==1){

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$username=$rows['username'];
$password=$rows['password'];
$name=$rows['name'];
$phone=$rows['phone'];
$email=$rows['email'];
$country=$rows['country'];
$state=$rows['state'];

$tbl_name2="users";

// Insert data "users"
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(username, password, name, phone, email, country, state)VALUES('$username', '$password', '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$country', '$state')";
$result2=mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
}

// if passkey not found
else {
echo "Oops, Something Went Wrong.<br/>Please reregister. Inconvinience is regretted.";
}

// if successfully moved from "temp_users" to "users"
if($result2){ Line 55..

echo "Thank you.<br/>Your account has been activated.<br/><a href=https://abc/owner_login.php>Click Here To Login</a>";

// Delete information "temp_user" with this passkey
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
}
}
?>
```

Seeking help on this. Error reporting added already.

Comment: This `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);` you're using the wrong API. Add an `i` to it.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` during development which would've caught that.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have the error reporting added and it shows the error which tried every bit..

Comment: Again, this line `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);` you are mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions. They don't mix.

Comment: I corrected that still says, mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given (Line 28).. and Undefined variable: result2 in (Line 55)

Comment: Try removing the `$con` from it `$count=mysqli_num_rows($result1);` because you're using `$con` twice.

Comment: Plus did you change `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);` to `$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);`?

Comment: Try `$sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'");` then remove `$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);` and change `if($result1){` to `if($sql1{` then do `$count=mysqli_num_rows($con, $sql1);`

Comment: Freat, removing $con fixed first error.. Yes I added $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result1); but Undefined variable: result2 in (Line 55) still appears..

Comment: You may need to move your `if($result2){` above your `oops`

Comment: I am sorry Freat above supposed to be Great...
Now the same error shows above oops instead of below..May be I got some isse with whole script..

Comment: Take it step by step. I'd like to help more, but setting up a DB would  just be too much right now; I'm exhausted.

Comment: I appreciate this much.. I will figure it out.. Thanks again..

Comment: and change also `mysqli_error()` to `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: `$result2` is defined only if `$count==1`. so add `$result2 = false;` after line 28 and before `if($count==1){...`

Comment: Thanks @aldanux, I just did..

Comment: Thanks @Janaka, I got it working.. had a long day.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 28 : `$count=mysqli_num_rows($result1);`

and after line 28 and before `if($count==1){...` add new line `$result2 = false;`

otherwise you are defining `$result2` only if `$count == 1`